# Navigate to viewModel and pass Model value

Tags: json, viewmodel, durandal

I am getting the data from server in JSON and I am converting that to my `viewModal`. Now I am loading the a new view using return `router.navigate('results')`. But at the same time I want to pass the `viewModel` which I created from the JSON object to be passed to this view. By default the "results" `viewModel` is getting called but it is having blank values.
A small code snippet will be helpful as I am new to Durandal JS.

Comment: please add code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finally something like this.

1. In the module where I want to navigate, I created an "Initialize" function which accepts a JSON object. Using this JSON object I initialized all properties in the viewModel.
2. From the page from where I have to navigate there I did a "require" on the module where I want to navigate next. Then I called the "Initialize" method and passed my JSON object.
3. After this I used router.navigate method to go that module.

This way when I navigated, I got all the values which I wanted to pass from one view to other. Hope this approach will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I have is to store that information in a separate module, like so:

### storage.js

```
define(function(require) { return []; });
```

### viewmodel.js

```
define(['storage'], function(storage) {

    $.get('uri', function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(obj) {
            storage.push(obj);
        });
    }); 
});
```

This is not the most elegant solution. I'm really interested if there is a clean way to pass data from and to separate view models on activation, but so far I have found none.

Comment: Please check the answer which I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Matthew is certainly similar to the way that I currently do it, once the data is held within your separate module (i have a path called modules/data/someDataStorage) you can use either events or a knockout observable to make the data update through to your view models.

In your case I would make updates to your shared module to store information on your request and then on the activation of your results module, go and get the data from that shared module.

Comment: Please check my solution. I kept it here as answer.